# Вывод 300 тысяч записей в Django с пагинацией

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне нужно вывести сотни тысяч записей в виде таблицы с пагинацией. Использую Django 2.0.3.

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.views import View
from parsercore.models import LogEntry as Entries


class IndexView(View):
    template_name = 'parsercore/search.html'
    #form_class = UrlForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}

        return render_to_response(self.template_name, context=context)


class ResultView(View):
    template_name = 'parsercore/result-page.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_entries'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last log entries.""" 
        entry_count = Entries.objects.count()
        print('количество записей в выборке ', entry_count)
        return Entries.objects.order_by('timestamp')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}

        search_entries = self.get_queryset()

        paginator = Paginator(search_entries, 50)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        print('page: ', page)
        if page is None:
            page = 1
        results = paginator.get_page(page)

        context['results'] = results
        context['result_lists'] = search_entries

        return render_to_response(template_name='parsercore/result-page.html', context=context)
```

**models.py**

```
import os
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import datetime


class LogFilePath(models.Model):
    """
    Allows for multiple logs to be stored in the same
    path, saving on database usage and allowing for easy
    migration of the database from one server to another.
    """

    path = models.TextField(
        unique=False,
        help_text=_("The base path for one or more log files."),
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.path




class LogFile(models.Model):
    """
    Representation of a log file.
    """

    path = models.ForeignKey(
        LogFilePath,
        help_text=_("The base path for this log file."),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    filename = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        help_text=_("The base file name of the log file within the base path."),
    )

    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        help_text=_("When this log file was created in the database."),
    )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        help_text=_("The last date/time that this log file was modified."),
    )

    parsed = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("The date/time at which this log file was completely parsed."),
    )


    def __unicode__(self):
        return os.path.join(u'%s' % self.path, u'%s' % self.filename)




class LogEntry(models.Model):
    """
    A single web log entry from a specific log file.
    """

    log_file = models.ForeignKey(
        LogFile,
        help_text=_("The log file in which this entry was found."),
        db_index=True,
        related_name='entries',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    remote_host = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text=_("The remote host which made the request (%%h)."),
    )
    client_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text=_("RFC 1413 identity of the client (%%l)."),
    )
    user_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text=_("The user ID of the user requesting the document (%%u)."),
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        help_text=_("The date/time that the request was received (%%t)."),
        db_index=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=datetime.date.today
    )
    method = models.TextField(
        help_text=_("The method of request line from the client (%%r)."),
    )
    request = models.TextField(
        help_text=_("The request line from the client (%%r)."),
    )
    status = models.CharField( #Integer
        max_length=100,
        help_text=_("The status code that the server sent back to the client (%%>s)."),
        db_index=True,
    )
    bytes_returned = models.CharField( #Integer
        max_length=100,
        help_text=_("The size of the object returned to the client (%%b)."),
    )
    referer = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("The \"Referer\" HTTP request header (\\\"%%{Referer}i\\\")."),
    )
    user_agent = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("The \"User-Agent\" HTTP request header (\\\"%%{User-Agent}i\\\")."),
        db_index=True,
    )
    session_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("The session ID, if any, depending on whether this is configured."),
        db_index=True,
    )

    # metadata parameters built up from entries
    path = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("The path requested from the web server."),
    )
    is_robot = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Was this request generated by some sort of robot?"),
    )
    is_page = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text=_("Was the response most likely an HTML document?"),
    )


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('log entry')
        verbose_name_plural = _('log entries')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return _("Request at %(timestamp)s from %(remote)s") % {'timestamp': self.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"),
            'remote': self.remote_host}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'parsercore'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^show/', views.ResultView.as_view(), name='show'),
]
```

и

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from parsercore import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'search/', include('parsercore.urls', namespace='search')),
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('parsercore.urls', namespace='search')),
]
```

**result-page.html**

```
{% extends 'parsercore/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Поиск по результатам" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
    <h1>Результаты</h1>
    {% if result_lists %}
       <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead class="thead-dark"><tr>
           <th scope="col">IP</th>
           <th scope="col">Дата</th>
           <th scope="col">Метод</th>
           <th scope="col">Запрос</th>
           <th scope="col">Код</th>
           <th scope="col">Размер ответа</th>
       </tr></thead><tbody>
        {% for result in result_lists %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ result.remote_host }}</td>
                <td>{{ result.timestamp }}</td>
                <td>{{ result.method }}</td>
                <td>{{ result.request }}</td>
                <td>{{ result.status }}</td>
                <td>{{ result.bytes_returned }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody></table>
        <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if results.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ results.number }} of {{ results.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if results.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ results.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

    {% else %}
        <p>Не найдено записей в бд по вашему запросу<br>Попробуйте загрузить файл еще раз</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Страница нормально работает до тысячи записей. При устранении ограничения количества страница не загружается, обработка проходит в течение минуты, потом в консоли появляется сообщение `MemoryError`. Мне надо также сделать статистику(может быть с помощью фильтрации) по тому же запросу.

**UPD:** решение найдено, смотрите в комментариях.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Ну вы сами поставили ограничение на число записей через `[:900]`, не?

Comment: @andreymal, нет. Если поставить больше тысячи, пагинатор перестает работать.

Comment: @Elefanobi больше подробностей, каким образом перестаёт?

Comment: @andreymal, paginator имеет параметры has_previous и has_next, в темплейте они используются в условии, чтобы рендерить кнопки вперед и назад. Если поставить больше тысячи записей, эти кнопки исчезают, значит свойства равны False.

Comment: Очень странно, в реализации пагинатора вроде бы нет ничего такого, что его сломало бы от более чем тысячи объектов

Comment: Приведите [mcve] без всяких `[:900]`, который не работает на более чем тысяче объектов, а то, похоже, сейчас вам никто не верит)

Comment: @andreymal, я добавил код и дополнил описание.

Comment: А зачем вы создаёте и используете используете result_lists? В нём все-все-все объекты без какой-либо пагинации, естественно будет MemoryError. У вас же есть `results.object_list`, содержащий 50 объектов на страницу — его и используйте

Comment: @andreymal, вы правы, выводится быстро по 50 записей на страницу и с любым количеством записей.